# getting "Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier." error and i dont know why

Tags: matlab

```
function [Nro_orden] = Contar_DNI(archivo,DNI)
fid = fopen(archivo,'a+')
i = 1;
if fid == -1 
    error('El programa no pudo abrirse correctamente')
else
    while ~feof(fid)
        line = fgetl(fid);
            cuentas{i} = textscan(line, '%d %s %s','delimiter',';');
            Rep_DNI(i) = strcmp(DNI,cuentas{i}{3})
            i = i+1;
    end
end
fclose(fid)
Nro_orden = sum(Rep_DNI);
end
```

sorry for it being in spanish, basically this funtion opens a document and checks the amount of times the argument is repeated in said txt file, but suddenly im getting this error and i have no idea why, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: You are opening the file in “append” mode, but you only read. You should open in read mode (`'r'`).

Comment: Also, the `fclose` call is illegal if `fid` is negative, move it to be inside the `else` clause.